# Applying Flip animation to UIPageViewController iOS Xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, viewflipper, flip

I want a book like feel for my app. For this, I have a UIPageViewController which scrolls through a number of pages. Everything works fine. Currently, the Transition type of the UIPageViewController is Page curl, but I want to implement something more like a flip (like a hard cover page turn).

I have implemented the following:-

```
public new UIViewController GetNextViewController(UIPageViewController pageViewController, UIViewController referenceViewController)
  {
   var page = referenceViewController as IpadNewController;
   var index = page.pageIndex;
   index ++;
   if(index == numberOfPages)
   {
    return null;
   }
   else{
    return ViewControllerAtIndex (index);
   }

  }

  public new UIViewController GetPreviousViewController(UIPageViewController pageViewController, UIViewController referenceViewController)
  {

   var page = referenceViewController as IpadNewController;
   var index = page.pageIndex;
   if(index == 0)
   {
    return null;

   }else{
    index --;
    return ViewControllerAtIndex (index);
   }


  }
```

**EDIT**

```
    private void LoadData(List<Models.NewsModel> viewPages)
      {
       if (viewPages != null)
       {
        if (viewPages.Count % 5 == 0)
        {
         numberOfPages =  viewPages.Count / 5;

        }
        else
        {
         numberOfPages =  viewPages.Count / 5 + 1;

        }
       }
       this.DataSource = this;
       var startingViewController = this.ViewControllerAtIndex(0);
       var viewControllers = new UIViewController[] { startingViewController };
       if (startingViewController != null)
       {
        this.SetViewControllers(viewControllers, UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, false, null);
       }
       this.View.Frame = View.Bounds;

      }
private IpadNewController ViewControllerAtIndex(int index)
      {
       if (numberOfPages == 0 || index >numberOfPages)
       {
        return null;
       }
       else
       {
        newIpadController = (IpadNewController)this.Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("iPadNew_VC");

        newIpadController.pageIndex = index;

       }
       return newIpadController;
      }
```

Is there a way I can change the Transition animation to a flip instead of curl without using any external libraries?

Answer (score 0):

At the `UIPageViewController` level you only have `PageCurl` and `Scroll` transitions for a `UIViewController`

Instead of using `UIPageViewController`, you could implement your own View container and use a `TransitioningDelegate` to define an animation for your series of `UIViewController` and apply it to the `UIViewController.TransitioningDelegate` property of each of your `UIViewController`.

Xamairn has a sample called `LookInside` that uses a custom presention controller that implements custom transition.

Ref: https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monotouch/ios8/LookInside/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Iam using a single UIVIewController. I am just replacing the views on it when the page is flipped. How can I implement that?

Comment: @helloworld I do not understand your comment as your question says you are using a `UIPageViewController`. If you only have one UIViewController and are removing and add `View`'s how are you getting the `PageCurl`s?

Comment: @SushilHangover I have added more code for clarity.

Comment: Could you give me an example on how to implement your solution as I am pretty new to iOS